# Eclipse Phonegap cannot load external string file using jquery .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, eclipse, cordova

I have a simple **index.html** file to display a string from **test.txt** file using the **.load** function from jquery library and put the string content to html *(div class="konten")*.

This the following HTML script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lib/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lib/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
...
<body onload="init();">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="konten"></div>
    </div>
</body>
...
```

and the js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.konten').load('test.txt',function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
      if(statusTxt=="success")
        alert("External content loaded successfully!");
      if(statusTxt=="error")
        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });
});
```

when I try to run the **index.html** file on the desktop browser (quick test), there is not displaying the content of **test.txt**, and showing the javascript alert **Error: 404: error**.

Is there anything wrong with the script that I wrote?

> HTML editor : Eclipse 4.2.2 (Juno)
>
> cordova-1.9.0
>
> jquery-2.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below login. By this way, you can invoke the required function based on whether you are using a desktop browser or in a mobile app.

```
function onBodyLoad() {
    // these are useful later in the app, might as well set early
    window.isRipple = (window.tinyHippos != null);
    window.isPhoneGap = /^file:\/{3}[^\/]/i.test(window.location.href);
    window.isIOS = !window.isRipple && navigator.userAgent.match(/(ios|iphone|ipod|ipad)/gi) != null;
    window.isAndroid = !window.isRipple && navigator.userAgent.match(/(android)/gi) != null;

    // stuff I use for debugging in chrome
    if (window.isPhoneGap) {
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
       onDeviceReady();
    }
}
```

You can call this function on body load event of the page.

```
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
```

I remember seeing this logic posted by someone else in SO. The real credit should go to that user.

Comment: and where I should put the **.load** jquery function? I'ts run well on emulator, but still give **Error: 404: error** on Desktop Browser (Google Chrome).

Comment: Thanks before, i just found out that it's a **bug from Google Chrome** (i think). I try using Mozilla Firefox, and it's both run well on Emulator and on Firefox.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Try your code inside the deviceready event instead of document ready event.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   $('.konten').load('test.txt',function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
     if(statusTxt=="success")
        alert("External content loaded successfully!");
     if(statusTxt=="error")
        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. The content of file test.txt appears when running on the emulator, but does not show up if we run the index.html file on the desktop browser (Google Chrome). I use a desktop browser as a temporary replacement for the Android Emulator which running slow. I think if use the Desktop Browser will give the same result given the script used is HTML, CSS and Javascript

Comment: Added another solution based on your last comment